# How to name variable Inside of for loop

Tags: node.js, server

I wanted to create a loop that creates HTTP servers in Node.JS, where it creates `server1`, `server2`, etc. as const's. My problem is that I cannot get it to create a new server with a specific name based on a var. This is what I have right now.

```
const http = require('http')
const server=new http.createServer(function(res,req){res.write('Hi');res.end()})
for (let i=1001;i<9999;i++){
    if (i=8080||i==3000||) return; //I'm already using 8080, 3000, and I don't want to use less than 1000.
    const server${i}=new http.createServer(function(res,req){res.write('Hi');res.end()})
}
```

Obviously the `${i}` thing won't work,

Comment: 1. Variables are scoped so no need to change a name here. 2. You can't create variable names dynamically like that. You wanted to use an array.

Comment: This is invalid syntax as well `if (i=8080||i==3000||)`

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create an array of servers, and push to it a server object like:

```
const servers = []

for (let i=1001;i<9999;i++){
  servers.push({
     name: `server${i}`,
     server: new http.createServer(function(res,req){res.write('Hi');res.end()})
  })
}
```

now to access a specific server you could do `servers.find(s => s.name === 'server999')?.server`

Comment: A dictionary could be a better idea depending on the usage